# I just switched over to Python3 and I can't set it to be my default version of python

Tags: python, version, default

When searching for a solution for my problem, all advice points towards just prepending my `$PATH` variable with the path to that version of Python, but that doesn't help.

Here's my .bash_profile:

```
PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:~/bin"
export PATH="~/bin/python/anaconda:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4:$PATH"

PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4:${PYTHONPATH}
```

---

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

---

```
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print(p)
...

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Comment: Use `python3` instead of `python`? If it works but you still want to use `python`, you can `alias python=python3`. Not sure about the side-effects of that though.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all *nix systems like MacOSX, most Linux distributions, expect `python` to refer to Python 2; `python3` to Python 3. If you change this, something might break badly. Thus even though the [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) talks about the "default" python distribution for `python`, and that all Python 2 scripts would use `python2` in shebang, it is not the fact yet. Many programs expect `python` to stand for `python2`.

Furthermore even in such a system you still should prefix your scripts with `python3` and explicitly run your Python 3 programs with that command. Just prefix your scripts with something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and it should work.

---

If you are bugged about python 2.7 opening whenever you execute `python`, do an alias in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias python=python3
```

---

Also I am not sure if whatever you are doing with `PYTHON_PATH` is wise; the python interpreter will know where to look for its own libraries without this hackery.

Comment: I already have alias set up for python to run python3, but that's not the problem. My problem is that putting the path to my version of python at the front of my $PATH variable (or $PYTHONPATH?) is supposed to make `which python` show that path, but it doesn't.

Comment: As I said: you **must not** get the Python 3 interpreter with `which python`

Comment: Further more, I don't even have `/usr/bin/python` in my PATH at all.

Answer (score -2):

The author of the suggestion that solved my problem deleted their post already, but the command `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4` did the trick.

Comment: It does the "trick" but this **WILL** break the behaviour of many Python 2 scripts being used by the system, or installed application. Until python3 becomes a default and a community wide decision is made to switch from py2 to py3, keep both runtimes in place.

Comment: BTW your `ln` command is has parameters set the wrong way around.

Comment: You should consider why the post was deleted.  I use OS X, Linux, and Windoze and py2 and py3 on all three.  Believe me, you don't want two programs named `python` and you don't want to overwrite the default.

Comment: ok, so `unlink /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4`?

Edit: nvm, should be `unlink /usr/bin/python`

Comment: I think you might have lost your python 2 by making that link - you might have broken it.  Personally I link /usr/bin/python3 to the Frameworks python3.4.  I'm not a fan of the #!/usr/env solution either (that's another argument).

Comment: Using /bin/env enables an user to have python default installed at another place than the system's default. This is a good thing.

Comment: @zmo:  There can be security issues with env, but maybe we should agree to disagree, I think the OP has bigger problems now he made that link.